# How to convert &trade; to TM using knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

Using knockout js,
Product name comes dynamically and its not convert to ™ to TM using ko.

I want to display TM instead of &trade ; in name.
Product name is like Test1™Test

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The product name should not contain HTML code in the first place. If the actual product name is `Test1™Test` then you should store `Test1™Test` in the database, not `Test1&trade;Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of text attribute use html attribute
ie

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
```